# Better way to loop over items in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am a beginner to Vue.JS and have recently encountered this problem. When looping over objects that are in a variable inside the `data` var, I have to add a span class to the component and then put the v-for inside that, and then add all of my HTML in there. Here is what I mean

```js
            data: {
                posts: [
                    { title : "My first post", author : "Seamus" },
                    { title : "Another post!", author : "Don" },
                    { title : "There are so many posts!", author : "Unknown" },
                ],
            }
```

As you can see, I have a posts list that is storing posts. (Note that I have registered the component in the component[] list.)
So this is the HTML

```html
        Vue.component("blog-post", {
            props: ["posts"],
            template: `
            <div>
                <span v-for="post in posts">
                    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                    <p>{{ post.author }}</p>
                </span>
            </div>
            `
        })
```

I have had to to put a span element that encompasses the rest of the elements. I was wondering if there was a more Vue-onic way of doing this. I know I am probably missing some info because I'm only new, however I would like to see if there is a better way to do this
Thanks :)

Comment: What's your issue exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use html tag, you can use `template`.
Example:

```
<template v-for="post in posts">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.author }}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is fine. Though, it is better to use list elements for this because they are more semantically correct. Then, add a :key attribute to the list items. See link for the sample: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html. The page will still work if the :key attribute is included but it helps to properly re-render the list.

Answer (score -1):

you can add  it in the `<div>`

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.author }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use v-for on a template's root element.